# How to plot a graph with a moving line cursor in sync with audio file on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, plot, cursor, line

So basically, I have to make a GUI which plots a .wav file. I want to include a moving line cursor that moves through the axes in sync with the audio that's played.

Basically, whenever I click on the "play-Audio" push button, the line should move across the plot following the exact time period of the Audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your audio data, I will create 5000 random points sampled at 1000 Hz for playback and plot

```
x=[randn(2500, 1)/10; randn(2500,1)*10]; % noise with a step change in the middle
fs = 1000;
time=(0:length(x)-1)/fs;
figure(1)
plot(time, x)
xlabel('Time (s)')
grid on
end_time = length(x)/fs;
```

Now I will create a red vertical line that will be moved along the data as it plays back.  The handle, h, needs to be stored so the x data can be updated

```
h=line([0,0],[-30,30],'color','r','marker', 'o', 'linewidth', 2);
```

Here is the code that would be run when the user hits the play button:

```
sound(x, fs) % starts playing the sound
tic % Starts Matlab timer
t=toc; % Gets the time since the timer started
while t<end_time
   set(h, 'xdata', t*[1,1]) % Moves the line to the time indicated by t
   drawnow % necessary to get figure updated
   t=toc; % get the current time for the next update
end
```

This code updates the line as fast as it can, so if you have a faster computer you will get more updates than if you had a slower computer.